# python parsing json without key

Tags: json, python-3.3

This feels like an easy question but I can't seem to find the answer.
I'm working in python 3.3 and have something I retrieved from a JSON that looks like this:

```
some_list = json_response['key']
# some_list == {'a':'b','c':'d','e':'f'}{'g':'h','i':'j','k':'l'}
```

I've been trying to access each {} on its own with no success.
What would be the easiest way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `some_list`'s value is `{'a':'b', 'c':'d','e':'f'}{'g':'h', 'i':'j', 'k':'l'}` string and you cannot change the way it is written/dumped into `json_response['key']`, you can replace `}{` with `},{` to have the dictionaries delimited and load the string with [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> some_list = "{'a':'b', 'c':'d','e':'f'}{'g':'h', 'i':'j', 'k':'l'}" 
>>> literal_eval(some_list.replace("}{", "},{").strip())
({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f'}, {'i': 'j', 'k': 'l', 'g': 'h'})
```

This is a *tuple* of dictionaries printed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I had with the value was that I couldn't tell whether it was JSON or not a lot of the times.
In the end I decided to go about the roundabout way of casting to string so I know what it is, and just using regex.